# Change font size of Toolbar title in CollapsingToolbarLayout in android

Tags: android, android-styles, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an Toolbar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) inside android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout and i want to change the font size of toolbar title. I have tried app:titleTextAppearance and some older suggestions but they don't work. my code is as bellow.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/route_detail_image"
            android:src="@drawable/default_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dip"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:background="@color/trans_black"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:elevation="20dp"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/route_title"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

inside my style.xml

```
<style name="route_title" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:color">#ffff0000</item>
</style>
```

inside .java

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(route_name);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got answer from [this link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175808#c7)

```
mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(getTitle());
mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppBar);
mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppBar);


<style name="ExpandedAppBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="CollapsedAppBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>

<style name="ExpandedAppBarPlus1" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">28.5sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="CollapsedAppBarPlus1" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">24.5sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
try 
{
    final Field field = collapsingToolbarLayout.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCollapsingTextHelper");
    field.setAccessible(true);

    final Object object = field.get(collapsingToolbarLayout);
    final Field tpf = object.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTextPaint");
    tpf.setAccessible(true);

    ((TextPaint) tpf.get(object)).setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Comment: not working. and it doesn't seem to do anything with toolbar title.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom layout to the `Toolbar` with size you want with `addView()`

Comment: I tried that too. but in that case the TextView disappears on collapsing. it doesn't work how it should.

Comment: are you using toolbar as action or standalone toolbar?